# Dismissing a UIpopover

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios

How do you dismiss a popover from within a navigation stack. I have a navigation controller as the root controller of the popover and 2 taes vies in the stack. So that the first table view pushes the second and the second should dismiss the popover. I could pass a reference from table to table of the popover though this seems wrong. What is the preferred way of dismissing a popover after navigated through different controllers?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your appdelegate, add a new NSNotificationCenter observer:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                         selector:@selector(hidePopover)
                                             name:@"hidePopover" 
                                           object:nil];
```

Once you have that setup, add a new method within the appdelegate like so:

```
-(void)hidePopover{
    [UIPopoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
}
```

This approach is great, because now you have things set up in such a way that you can close the popover from anywhere. You do this like so:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"hidePopover" 
                                                    object:nil];
```

Hope this solves your conundrum,

Zane

Comment: But dismissPopover method is not a class method. So I'd need a reference to the popover in the app delegate?? Why can't it just work like modal view controllers?

Comment: If you read the apple docs, they say to keep a reference to the popover controller as a property in your header, so that the view does not have to be created every time it is shown. You would replace UIPopOverController with the name of your object. Sorry, I should have been more clear about that.

Comment: Is that in the UIPopoverController class reference?

Comment: Yeah, just replace the UIPopoverController part with the name of your object reference (myPopover)