# Getting a reference to the UIPopover that pops up in the context of a UISplitViewController in iPad Landscape

Tags: ipad, ios4, uisplitviewcontroller, uipopovercontroller, uipopover

This is a follow up question to [Dismissing a UIpopover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4779962/dismissing-a-uipopover) regarding how to dismiss a popover.

I have a similar situation but its a UIPopover in the context of a Master Detail iPad application. I basically create TWO Navigation Controllers (this is off a recommendation from CS193P), one for the Master and one for the Detail.

in my AppDelegate, I have the following to set up my UISplitViewController

```
#pragma 
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

// Creating the EpisodesViewController (used on both iPhone and iPad)
EpisodesViewController *navControllerRootController = [[EpisodesViewController alloc] init];
UINavigationController *masterNav = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:navControllerRootController];
[navControllerRootController release];
masterNav.title=@"Episodes";

if ([self iPad]) {
    EpisodeDetailViewController *detailViewController = [[EpisodeDetailViewController alloc]init];
    UINavigationController *detailNav = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:detailViewController];
    detailNav.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];

    self.splitviewController = [[UISplitViewController alloc] init];
    self.splitviewController.delegate=detailViewController;
    self.splitviewController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:masterNav,detailNav,nil];
    [window setRootViewController:self.splitviewController];

    [detailViewController release];
    [detailNav release];
}else {
    [window setRootViewController:masterNav];
} 
[masterNav release];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
}
```

So. the question is... how do i get a reference to the UIPopover that appears when I click the "Episodes" button. What I'd like to do is implement the solution from that other thread, but I dont have a reference (that I know of) to my popover so I can dismiss it.

[Edit] made the way that I created the detailNav the same as the way I created masterNav to avoid clouding the main issue.

Comment: Okay, I've for it figured out.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I've got it.

I used a combination of the notification approach described here [Dismissing a UIpopover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4779962/dismissing-a-uipopover) .. I post th notification from the

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

in my Master view and I have an instance variable pointing to the UIPopover as described here

[UISplitViewController in portrait: how to hide master popover programatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5721583/uisplitviewcontroller-in-portrait-how-to-hide-master-popover-programatically/6050932#6050932) which I use to actually dismiss the popover.

Works like a charm.

:-)